# SVN Revision history returning incorrect commits

Tags: svn

I'm working on ingesting the commits from the following repo by day, but I'm getting some weird behavior from SVN log:
http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo

However, when I'm trying to get some data by bins, SVN log appears to be reporting incorrect data.

For example:
svn log -r {2006-06-23}:{2006-06-01} --limit 10

Returns no data, but there are revisions in that directory for the time range [see revision id 46634 on Jun 03 2006 for an example].

There are also some other aberrations around those dates:
Making a call to log with '--revision {2006-06-02}:2435' returns revision 46691 on date Jun 06 2006.

I understand there are some odd behaviors around how it maps revisions to days [namely that the "date" will map to the most recent revision as of that day.], but that doesn't seem to apply here.

I'm almost at the point of calling the SVN revision filtering broken, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `{2006-06-23}:{2006-06-01}` "oldest" (left) revision is yonger than right. It's incorrect. "From 1 June 2006 to 23 June 2006" must be oldestdate:newestdate range
2. Just don't use revision-date mix in ranges, select one policy

Comment: (1) That's the suggested way to invert the sort from the docs.
(2) This is also supported, but I do need it to capture commits by day.  Asking for a full revision range i.e. r0:HEAD returns an error [this folder didn't exist until r2435], and asking for a full date range gives me way too much data.  Changing the second select {2006-06-02}:{1970-01-01}, produces the same errant results.  That is, I get a revision from "2006-06-06 08:46:55 -0400 (Tue, 06 Jun 2006)"

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, which was to specify the start and end times of the day, like:
{1992-01-01T23:59:59.999999}:2435